# Enable Sympy auto-symbols mode from a running interpreter

Tags: python, ipython, sympy

The `isympy` command startes an interpreter with sympy imported. I can additionally offers these options start an interpreter in 'interactive mode':

```
  -a, --auto-symbols    automatically construct missing symbols
  -i, --int-to-Integer  automatically wrap int literals with Integer
  -I, --interactive     equivalent to -a -i
```

Is there a way to enable this model after importing Sympy in a standard Python or IPython interpreter?
This would be particularly useful for working with Jupyter notebooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the source code of `isympy`, you'll see that it essentially just parses the command line options into arguments for the `sympy.interactive.init_session()` function. You could therefore run that function with required arguments in your Jupyter notebook session which is also [suggested in the docs](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.3/tutorial/printing.html#setting-up-pretty-printing).

Comment: that is the answer, but it does not work due to a bug https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2839

Comment: Sorry to hear that. At least they seem to be working on it.

Comment: I do not understand how the isympy script can still work though. I have verified that `sympy.interactive.init_session(ipython=True, auto_int_to_Integer=True, auto_symbols=True)` does not have the desired effect, but that is all that the isympy script appears to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I dug a little more into the code following Ondrej's answer and found a way around the bug:

Althoug calling:

```
ipython.interactive.init_session(ipython=None, auto_symbols=True, auto_int_to_Integer=True)
```

does not work in running IPython,
in a standard Python console it starts an IPython session and initializes it as expected.

The reason it does not work from IPython is that the bulk of the initialization work in `init_session` is done in a call to `ipython.interactive.session.init_ipython_session`.
However, `init_session` checks if it is already in an IPython session and skips the `init_ipython_session` call if it is.
Since the `init_ipython_session` is the first meaningful thing the `init_ipython` can do, the problem can be fixed by explicitly calling init_ipython_session` first:

```
from sympy.interactive import init_session
from sympy.interactive.session import init_ipython_session
init_ipython_session(auto_symbols=True, auto_int_to_Integer=True)
init_session(ipython=None, auto_symbols=True, auto_int_to_Integer=True)
```

This puts a running Ipython session into the desired mode.
However, the intialization only takes effect in the next "cell".
For example pasting the above code into an IPython console together with code that relies on the inirializations will fail.
The initialization and the code relying on it must be pasted in separately.
In a jupyter notebook the above code must be in a separate cell.